# Scrubbing data after a character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do i scrub the last part of the below text to retrieve data only till .xls?

```
/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.xls, 247 KB, 06/11/2013
```

I need only this part, `/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.xls`

I tried using below command but didn't work as expected.

> Selected Regular Expression and Wrap Around. Match case Checked
>
> Find what: , [0-9].*
>
> Replace with:(leave empty)

Answer (score 0):

try to find the regular expression `xls,.*$` and replace it with `xls`. Your regex will match any coma followed by a numerical character, it is too broad.

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic expression that would match .pdf, .xlsx, .csv etc..My Reg ex is working for most of the cases, but special cases as described above, this is failing.

Comment: well in the present example the regex `, [0-9].*` should match everything after Jan. Can you post more lines of your file so we can try to find a general expression ?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.\S+\K,.+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\.      # a dot
\S+     # 1 or more non spaces
\K      # forget all we've seen until this position
,       # a comma
.+      # 1 or more any character but newline
$       # end of line
```

**Given:**

```
/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.xls, 247 KB, 06/11/2013
/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.pdf, 247 KB, 06/11/2013
/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.csv, 247 KB, 06/11/2013
```

**Result for given example:**

```
/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.xls
/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.pdf
/Artifacts & Supporting Docs/AR.01 - WLCE cohort schema Rel 3.0 final Jan, 3, 2013.csv
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]